# Thermodynamics: What is the entropy change of an electrical resistance taken as system?

Tags: thermodynamics, electric-circuits, entropy

Consider a system consisting only of an electrical resistor through which a constant current is flowing. Simultaneously, it is rejecting heat such that its temperature is constant throughout the process. With this much of information, what can we conclusively say about the entropy change of the system?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the resistor at thermodynamic equilibrium when current is flowing through it?   Are you assuming that temperature is uniform radially and axially throughout the resistor when the current is flowing through it, or is only its average temperature the same value as initially?

Comment: @ChesterMiller Yes, it is at thermodynamic equilibrium. And yes, it has a uniform temperature.

Comment: It can't have a uniform temperature if it is rejecting heat.  Its surface temperature has to be lower than its average temperature.  As a result, it is not in thermodynamic equilibrium.

Comment: If the current is $I$ in a resistor $R$ at temperature $T$ then it generates $\dot q = I^2 R$ heat flux (joule per second) and  $\dot s = \frac {\dot q}{T}= \frac {I^2 R}{T}$ entropy rate (joule per kelvin per second) that increases the entropy of the *environment* not that of the resistor. In steady state the entropy of the resistor is constant and it depends on $T$ and its material but does not depend on the current.

Comment: @hyportnex Steady state does not necessarily mean thermodynamic equilibrium.  So, at steady state, there will be temperature gradients within the resistor in order for generated heat to be conducted out.  Are you willing to accept the concept that the entropy can be defined and calculated for a system that is not at thermodynamic equilibrium?

Comment: @Chester Miller I said nothing about thermodynamic equilibrium, my comments were about steady state.

Comment: @Chester Miller I said nothing about thermodynamic equilibrium, my comments were about steady state. Assume a very small resistor relative to the very large thermal block. And yes, I believe and my understanding is (if you can call it that way) that entropy just as well definable in equilibrium as in nonequilibrium, see Bridgman's one-page beauty "The Second Law of Thermodynamics and Irreversible Processes", Phys. Rev. 58, 845; my problem is that my understanding is quite slim....

Comment: @hyportnex So you are accepting the concept that the entropy can be defined and calculated for a system like this that is not at thermodynamic equilibrium, correct?  Since in steady state heat conduction, the temperature T varies with spatial position within the material, what value of T do you use to calculate the entropy.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50614/discussion-between-hyportnex-and-chester-miller).

Answer (score 2):

The differential equation for steady state heat conduction within the resistor (neglecting axial conduction) is given by:
$$k\frac{1}{r}\frac{d}{dr}\left(r\frac{dT}{dr}\right)+\frac{I^2R}{\pi r_0^2L}=0\tag{1}$$where k is the thermal conductivity of the resistor material, $r_0$ is the outer radius of the resistor (assumed cylindrical), T is the temperature (a function of r), r is the radial location, and L is the length of the resistor.  The solution to this equation for the temperature profile within the resistor, subject to the condition that the mass average temperature is $T_{ave}$ is given by:  $$T=T_{ave}+\frac{I^2R}{8\pi k L}\left[1-2\left(\frac{r}{r_0}\right)^2\right]\tag{2}$$
If the current to the resistor were suddenly shut off and the resistor were suddenly insulated, transient heat conduction would cause the temperature of the resistor to eventually equilibrate to $T_{ave}$.  Since this process would take place spontaneously and adiabatically, we would expect the entropy of the resistor in this final equilibrium state to be higher than the entropy with the current flowing and heat being rejected (given that the average temperatures are the same in both cases).

The entropy of the resistor operating at steady state with the current flowing (and heat being rejected) minus the entropy of the resistor at the final uniform  average temperature is given by:$$\Delta S=\rho C L\int_0^{r_0}{2\pi r \ln{(T/T_{ave})}}dr\tag{3}$$where $\rho$ is the material density and C is its heat capacity.
If we substitute Eqn. 2 into Eqn. 3 and carry out the indicated integration, we obtain (if I integrated correctly):
$$\Delta S=mC\left[\ln{(1-\beta)-1}+\frac{(1+\beta)}{2\beta}\ln{\left(\frac{1+\beta}{1-\beta}\right)}\right]\tag{4}$$where m is the mass of the resistor and $$\beta=\frac{I^2R}{8\pi k L T_{ave}}\tag{5}$$As we indicated above, we expect this entropy difference to be less than zero (i.e., the entropy of the resistor at steady state with the current flowing and rejecting heat to the surroundings should be less than the entropy of the resistor in the final state at the same average temperature $T_{ave}$.  Therefore, the expression involving $\beta$ in Eqn. 4 should always be negative.  If we use Taylor series expansions to evaluate the expression involving $\beta$ in Eqn. 4 in the limit of small values of $\beta$, be obtain:
$$\Delta S=-\frac{mC\beta^2}{6}\tag{6}$$  As expected this entropy difference is negative.

Comment: If the system is in steady state, then by definition none of its properties can change with time. This is irrespective of how you are going to define it or calculate it. No offense, but your answer seems to be for the question "What is change in entropy of resistor before and after turning on of current through resistor", but as far as I understand it, that's not what OP asked. If I am wrong, OP must clarify.

Comment: Yes.  Your interpretation of what my answer addresses is correct.  At least, that was my understanding of what he was asking.  But, for certain, the question was not very precisely worded.

Answer (score 1):

(*I am assuming that temperature is constant in the resistor. If you want, think about it as a quasi-1D object*)

If we assume the system to be stationary, then all the thermodynamic parameters in the resistance will be constant. Therefore, since entropy is a state function, the entropy change in any given time interval will be $0$: the system is increasing its entropy by absorbing energy from the battery, but since we are assuming that $T$ is constant it means that it is simultaneously releasing the same quantity of energy in the environment, thus decreasing its entropy.

The medium to which the resistance is giving off its heat, on the other hand, will heat up, and its entropy will increase. Using the formula for Joule heating, we have

$$dS = \frac {\delta Q} T = \frac{I^2 R dt}{T} \to \frac{dS}{dt}= \frac{I^2 R} T$$